# ng template binding with button tooltip is not working

Tags: angular, ng-template, property-binding

tolTemplate is not getting bind with [tooltip]

```
<ng-template #tolTemplate>
  Just another: 
</ng-template>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" [tooltip]="tolTemplate">
  Show me tooltip with html
</button>
```

Any idea, how to resolve this.

[image]\

Comment: Can you please provide more information to this? What you have bind to Show Tooltip button?

Comment: I was trying show a HTML with <ng-template #tolTemplate>Just another: " a HTML segment"</ng-template>

Comment: assign string value to tolTemplate variable that might solve your issue

Comment: I am asking the object(maybe it can be json) bind to that button tooltip

Comment: here is example what you want to achieve https://stackblitz.com/angular/rorynnredxy

Comment: have you solved your issue?

Comment: @SnehaPawar Not completely. Example provided by TheParam solve data binding issue, but now tooltip view is not available.

Comment: What is this `[toolTip]` is this a custom directory of yours? If you want a simple string tooltip you can use `title` attribute of html but to have a template you can use a third party library or your own directive.

Comment: I am using [tooltip] of `import { TooltipModule } from 'ng2-tooltip-directive';`

Comment: In that library `@Input('tooltip') tooltipValue: string;` says that the tooltip value should be a string. It can't be a template. If you want to use a template try another.

Comment: @Senal DO you havve any suggestion for the same ?

Comment: Try ngx-tooltip

Answer (score 0):

Try to add to button attribute **contentType** or **content-type** (depends on version angular).

```
<ng-template #tolTemplate>
  Just another: 
</ng-template>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" [tooltip]="tolTemplate" contentType="template">
  Show me tooltip with html
</button>
```